# PHP GD Image Watermark Quality

Tags: php, image, gd, watermark

I'am using PHP GD to copy an image (watermark) on another image.
Unfortunately the quality of the watermark is terrible.

I'm using quality 100% as the attribute, but it doesn't help.

Have you guys know any good way to increase the quality?

Regards.

Comment: Could you provide some examples of your code or let us know what filetype the image is?

Comment: Show some code - but if the watermark's source image is much smaller than the target final image, it's going to look like crap after being scaled up.

Answer (score 0):

A 90% quality should give you the exact same results and decrease the file size by half (on JPEG, OFC).

Try using `ImageCopyResampled()` instead of `ImageCopyResize()`, other than that I don't think you can do anything else with GD alone, maybe Imagick has some other tricks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any transparency, or is it just a solid square.  What exactly looks bad about the quality? The edges, the whole thing?

I like to use a 24bit transparent PNG for the watermark, and imagemagick to do the overlay, you get a lot of control over the final product that way.

**Lots of possibilities for watermark with imagemagick:**
http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/annotating/

Comment: Yes, I use some transparency.

Comment: Maybe you can tell me , how to copy an 'text image' with transparency using the way you prefer?